# Assign unique group per consecutive values under a threshold in pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a dataframe such as:

```
Groups  Names Values
G1      SP1   1
G1      SP1   5
G1      SP1   -2
G1      SP1   30
G1      SP1   50
G1      SP1   50
G1      SP1   -1
G1      SP1   2
G1      SP2   2
G1      SP2   20
G1      SP2   1
G2      SP3   30
G2      SP3   9
G2      SP3   3
G3      SP3   2
```

and I would like to add a `new_group` column for each `Groups-Names` where I found consecutive `Values < 10`

I should then get:

```
Groups  Names Values new_groups
G1      SP1   1      NG1
G1      SP1   5      NG1
G1      SP1   -2     NG1
G1      SP1   30     NG2
G1      SP1   50     NG3
G1      SP1   50     NG4
G1      SP1   -1     NG5
G1      SP1   2      NG5
G1      SP2   2      NG5
G1      SP2   20     NG6
G1      SP2   1      NG7
G2      SP3   30     NG8
G2      SP3   9      NG9
G2      SP3   3      NG9
G3      SP3   2      NG10
```

so for instance, since I get **Values < 10** for the first **3 rows**, I assign the first group: `NG1`

Then, I have a value > 10 (which is 30), so I assign the second group: `NG2`

Then, I get `value > 10` in `row5`, then I assign a new group : `NG3`
Then, I get again a `value > 10` in `row6`, then I assign a new group: `NG4`

and so on...

Here is the dataframe in dict format if it can help;

```
{'Groups': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G1', 4: 'G1', 5: 'G1', 6: 'G1', 7: 'G1', 8: 'G1', 9: 'G1', 10: 'G1', 11: 'G2', 12: 'G2', 13: 'G2',14:'G3'}, 'Names': {0: 'SP1', 1: 'SP1', 2: 'SP1', 3: 'SP1', 4: 'SP1', 5: 'SP1', 6: 'SP1', 7: 'SP1', 8: 'SP2', 9: 'SP2', 10: 'SP2', 11: 'SP3', 12: 'SP3', 13: 'SP3', 14 : 'SP3'}, 'Values': {0: 1, 1: 5, 2: -2, 3: 30, 4: 50, 5: 50, 6: -1, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 20, 10: 1, 11: 30, 12: 9, 13: 3, 14: 2}}
```

Comment: Why does value `50` fall into 2 groups `NG3` and `NG4` ?

Comment: since it is > 10.

Comment: That's not correct. If you put `1` and `5` into the same group `NG1`, then `9` and `3` should be in same `NG9`. Your output seems to be vague

Comment: Your are right for the last rows, sorry for that, I just updated the post.

Comment: @chippycentra does my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74771318/20603322) solves your problem?

Comment: @chippycentra, you may consider alternative short approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't find any better way to do it than just using the python function and then map it with pandas. This is not a very efficient way, but this'll do the job!

```py
#import
import pandas as pd

# Global Variable to know wether prv. one was <10
var = False

# Var. to hold prv. Grp no.
prv_grp = 0

# Function
def func(val):

    # Acessing the Variables, global as it's outside the func. scope
    global var
    global prv_grp

    if var: # If prv. val was <10

        if val < 10: # If it is still <10

            return "NG"+str(prv_grp) # Returning the value

        else: # If not

            var = False # To remember that this is not <10

            prv_grp += 1 # Increasing the grp

            return "NG"+str(prv_grp) # Returning the value 

        
    else: # If prv. value was not <10

        if val < 10: # But it is now

            var = True #To remember that this is <10

        
        prv_grp += 1 # Increasing the grp


        return "NG"+str(prv_grp) # Returning the value

     

# Your data
x = {
    'Groups': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G1', 4: 'G1', 5: 'G1', 6: 'G1', 7: 'G1', 8: 'G1', 9: 'G1', 10: 'G1', 11: 'G2', 12: 'G2', 13: 'G2'}, 

    'Names': {0: 'SP1', 1: 'SP1', 2: 'SP1', 3: 'SP1', 4: 'SP1', 5: 'SP1', 6: 'SP1', 7: 'SP1', 8: 'SP2', 9: 'SP2', 10: 'SP2', 11: 'SP3', 12: 'SP3', 13: 'SP3'}, 

    'Values': {0: 1, 1: 5, 2: -2, 3: 30, 4: 50, 5: 50, 6: -1, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 20, 10: 1, 11: 30, 12: 9, 13: 3}
}

# Converting to dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(x)

# Mapping the new_group column with an output of func. taking the Values column as input
df['new_groups'] = df['Values'].map(func)
```

Output:

```
print(df)

   Groups Names  Values new_groups
0      G1   SP1       1        NG1
1      G1   SP1       5        NG1
2      G1   SP1      -2        NG1
3      G1   SP1      30        NG2
4      G1   SP1      50        NG3
5      G1   SP1      50        NG4
6      G1   SP1      -1        NG5
7      G1   SP1       2        NG5
8      G1   SP2       2        NG5
9      G1   SP2      20        NG6
10     G1   SP2       1        NG7
11     G2   SP3      30        NG8
12     G2   SP3       9        NG9
13     G2   SP3       3        NG9
```

EDIT: Added Argument from Groups col. per op request from comment.

```py
# For understanding the code refer above code comments!

import pandas as pd

var = False

prv_grp = 0

grp_name = "" # For storing prv. or current  group name

def func(grp, val):

    global grp_name
    global var
    global prv_grp


    if grp == grp_name: # if group hasn't changed

        if var:

            if val < 10:

                return "NG"+str(prv_grp)

            else:

                var = False

                prv_grp += 1

                return "NG"+str(prv_grp)

            
        else: 

            if val < 10:

                var = True
            
            prv_grp += 1

            return "NG"+str(prv_grp)

    else: # If group name had changed

        grp_name = grp # Stroing the new Group name
        
        if val < 10:

            var = True
        
            prv_grp += 1

        else: 
            
            prv_grp += 1

            var = False

        return "NG"+str(prv_grp)
    



x = {
    'Groups': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G1', 4: 'G1', 5: 'G1', 6: 'G1', 7: 'G1', 8: 'G1', 9: 'G1', 10: 'G1', 11: 'G2', 12: 'G2', 13: 'G2', 14: 'G3'}, 

    'Names': {0: 'SP1', 1: 'SP1', 2: 'SP1', 3: 'SP1', 4: 'SP1', 5: 'SP1', 6: 'SP1', 7: 'SP1', 8: 'SP2', 9: 'SP2', 10: 'SP2', 11: 'SP3', 12: 'SP3', 13: 'SP3', 14: 'SP3'}, 

    'Values': {0: 1, 1: 5, 2: -2, 3: 30, 4: 50, 5: 50, 6: -1, 7: 2, 8: 2, 9: 20, 10: 1, 11: 30, 12: 9, 13: 3, 14: 2}
}

df = pd.DataFrame(x)

#df['new_groups'] = df['Values'].map(func)

# Here we are using lambda that send the value from Values to val arg & Groups to grp arg in func()
df['new_groups'] = df.apply(lambda x: func(grp = x.Groups, val = x.Values), axis=1)
```

Output:

```
print(df)

   Groups Names  Values new_groups
0      G1   SP1       1        NG1
1      G1   SP1       5        NG1
2      G1   SP1      -2        NG1
3      G1   SP1      30        NG2
4      G1   SP1      50        NG3
5      G1   SP1      50        NG4
6      G1   SP1      -1        NG5
7      G1   SP1       2        NG5
8      G1   SP2       2        NG5
9      G1   SP2      20        NG6
10     G1   SP2       1        NG7
11     G2   SP3      30        NG8
12     G2   SP3       9        NG9
13     G2   SP3       3        NG9
14     G3   SP3       2       NG10
```

Peace!

Comment: Thanks but can you take into account the groups and Names please? I edited to illustrated it. For instante the last row G3-SP3 is not ```NG9``` but rather ```NG10``` since it is not within the same groups ```G2-SP3``` as the previous row.

Comment: Hi, we are almost there ! There is juste the lines 12 and 13 that should be ```NG9```, and line 14 should be ```NG10```.

Comment: Found the problem, When the Group is changed but the value is > 10 the var is not set to False!

Answer (score 0):

Relatively short approach basing on accessing the previous values of `Values` column (using [`pandas.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html)) and compound boolean mask.
`True` values of `new_column` indicate positions where group index must be increased by 1, `False` - those positions that fall into previous group.

```
In [222]: df['new_group'] = ((df.Values > 10) | df.Values.shift().isna() | (df.Values.shift() > 10))

In [223]: group_idx = {'idx': 0}  # group indexer

In [224]: def set_groups(val, idx):
     ...:     if val:
     ...:         idx['idx'] += 1
     ...:     return 'NG{}'.format(idx['idx'])
     ...: 

In [225]: df['new_group'] = df['new_group'].apply(set_groups, idx=group_idx)

In [226]: df
Out[226]: 
   Groups Names  Values new_group
0      G1   SP1       1       NG1
1      G1   SP1       5       NG1
2      G1   SP1      -2       NG1
3      G1   SP1      30       NG2
4      G1   SP1      50       NG3
5      G1   SP1      50       NG4
6      G1   SP1      -1       NG5
7      G1   SP1       2       NG5
8      G1   SP2       2       NG5
9      G1   SP2      20       NG6
10     G1   SP2       1       NG7
11     G2   SP3      30       NG8
12     G2   SP3       9       NG9
13     G2   SP3       3       NG9
14     G3   SP3       2       NG9
```